# tensorflowのconv2d_transposeとはどのような処理なのでしょうか

Tags: python, tensorflow

tensorflowのconv2d_transposeの動作について調べたのですが、具体的にどのような処理を行うものなのか理解できません。
https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic
上のサイトにtransposeの処理のイメージを表すgif画像があるのですがそれを見てもいまいち意味がわかりません。
No padding, no strides, transposedのgif画像では、画像の周囲を0で埋めていますが、
paddingとは画像の周囲を埋めるものではないのでしょうか
どなたかconv2d_transposeとはどのような処理なのかご教授いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose
deconvolution直訳で逆畳み込み処理となり
乱暴な言い方をすると畳み込みの逆の操作を行います。
例えばご提示のページでNo padding, no stridesは4x4の画像を2x2に畳み込んでいますが
No padding, no strides, transposedは上記の逆の操作、2x2を4x4に戻しているとイメージしていただければ良いと思います。
実際通常の畳み込みとtransposedの動作は元画像と結果画像が逆になっているのが見て取れるかと思います。
paddingの動作も上記逆の操作を満たすように付与されるものとなります。